# When select onLongClickListener in the adapter class not give selected list item value and also select more than one list item?

Tags: java, android

I want to select list item only once but it selected more than one, when once click long press it select multiple list item when scroll, and when the toast message it gives random value from the listView, I want to give selected list item value.

```
if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mymessage, null, true);
            final View finalConvertView = convertView;
            convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    finalConvertView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFB2DFDB);
                    final String message2 = chatMessages.get(position).getMessageText();
                    final String msgid2 = chatMessages.get(position).getMessageID();
                    holder.delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            chatMessages.remove(position);
                            finalConvertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                            holder.delete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            ((ChatActivity)context).Edit(message2, msgid2);
                        }
                    });
                    return true;
                }
            });

        }else {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message, null, true);
            final View finalConvertView = convertView;
            ChatMessage chatMessage = getItem(position);


            convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {


                    final String replyuser = chatMessages.get(position).getReply_user();
                    final String message2 = chatMessages.get(position).getMessageText();
                    final String username = chatMessages.get(position).getMessageUser();
                    final String userid1 = chatMessages.get(position).getUserId();
                    final String msgid = chatMessages.get(position).getMessageID();
                    finalConvertView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFB2DFDB);
                    holder.reply.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.reply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class);
                            intent3.putExtra("user_id", userid1);
                            intent3.putExtra("message_id", msgid);
                            intent3.putExtra("replied_user_name", replyuser);
                          //  Toast.makeText(context,"Hello"+userid1+msgid,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            ((ChatActivity)context).Reply(username, message2);

                        }
                    });
                    return true;
                }
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Event Listeners](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#EventListeners):

> onLongClick() - This returns a boolean to indicate whether you have
>   consumed the event and it should not be carried further. That is,
>   return true to indicate that you have handled the event and it should
>   stop here; return false if you have not handled it and/or the event
>   should continue to any other on-click listeners.

For a ListView component, you may be using [OnItemLongClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener). The onItemLongClick() there uses a similar boolean return value to indicate whether it consumed the event.

`Return true :` mean that event is handled, no need for other event to trigger (like onClick)

`Return false` : mean that event is not handled. Other events can be raised, similar like bubble events in .NET WPF.

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(View view) {
    //your code
    return true; // or false
}
```

`OnItemLongClick` indicate that `LongClick` was activated and will cancel the trigger on the regular click. (like wrapper for `LongClick`).